# Innoscript - Getting current user profile informations

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to create a application using innoscript. I need to create/edit registry information values in HKLM. Hence I need admin privileges to install the application.

However, if a non admin user try to install the application, innoscript require admin user password, once they enter the admin user password, whenever I query the registry in installation script (say, HKCU), it retrieves information from the admin user. But I would like to get information from the currently logged in user. As a result, program installed under the admin user location instead of current logon user account.

Is there a way to get current logon user user and user app data location from innoscript, when the application is started with Run as administrator or prompted admin user.

Awaiting your update.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The installer is not supposed to read or modify any per-user state (including HKCU) during a per-machine installation (and there is no way to do so reliably).  You should instead make the application itself do this on first run (by trying to read the appropriate location and assuming default values if they were not found).

Remember, an application is installed once, but can then be run by several different users.  This behaviour is essential.

Comment: Thanks for not downvoting. But whether an installer should perform changes to a single user's area is subjective. So many installer allows you to install for all users, but some offers you an optioin also to install for current user only. It really depends on what software does this installer offer.

Comment: Inno doesn't support that option at install time at present.  You have to decide at compile time, because the elevation happens or not prior to any user input.  If the setup is non-elevated, then you can't install per-machine; if the setup is elevated, then you shouldn't install per-user (because you can't do so properly or without making a mess).

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround is to move your logic to an executable instead of Pascal script. Then you can call this executable in [Run] section,

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection

Remember to mark the Run item as runasoriginaluser.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this but I won't.  It's correct, but it's bad advice.  (The original user is sometimes the admin too, and this won't help a second user trying to run the app.)